# SQL to get characters in the middle of a field

Tags: mysql, substring

In my table I've got a field that's effectively an array, where all entries are structured as {"key1": value1, "key2": value2...}

I need to do some analysis based on just one of these keys, "email", but haven't been able to figure out how to return just the email address in my query because the lengths are variable. The beginning of the substring is predictably after "email" (quotes inclusive), and the ending is predictably ".com" (quotes non-inclusive).

Right now my query looks like this:

```
select substring(`fieldname`, locate('"email"', `fieldname`) + 9, 20) 
as 'Customer Email' 
from table 
where `fieldname` in ('email_processed', 'email_delivered')
```

So I get the 20 characters after the beginning of the address, but I don't know to make that dynamic to the end of the email suffix.

How can I isolate the email address within the field?

Comment: Couldn't you just locate the next key and use it's beginning (minus an appropriate amount) as the email's end? (...not saying it won't be ugly, but that is what happens when you cram data like this into one field).

Comment: Yep, that worked! I had been trying to define the length based on the email suffix, but they aren't all .com addresses. Using the next key did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just store the data properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by using the position of the subsequent key to define my endpoint (plus a little adjustment):

```
select substring(`fieldname`, locate("key1", `fieldname`) + 9, 
locate("key2", `fieldname`) - locate("key1", `fieldname`) - 12) 
as 'Customer Email'` 
from table
```